# How to check for string in online text file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.6, urllib

How do I check for a string from an online text file? Right now, I am using urllib.request to read the data, but how would I check for a string from an online text file?

Comment: What is it not working in your code at the moment?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the issue. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: If you dont want to read the file (in order to do the search) and you want to do it on the "server side" - you will have to have a web server with code that will get an API call with the user input. This API will return the match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that urllib perfectly matches your use case.

I do not understand why you opened the file when the text was already available in your variable, here's a corrected version of your code, using an online txt file as per your request, available on [www.w3.org](http://www.w3.org) website (you can clearly change the URL with whatever you prefer):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

textpage = urlopen("https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt")
text = str(textpage.read(), 'utf-8')

# Conditions
while True:
    check_input = str(input("What do you want to search? "))
    if check_input == "":  # if no value is entered for the string
        continue
    if check_input in text:  # string in present in the text file
        print("Matched")
        break
    else:  # string is absent in the text file
        print("No such string found, try again")
        continue
```

**Output**

```
What do you want to search? something
No such string found, try again
What do you want to search? SPACE
Matched
```

You can also use the requests library, here's a another example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import requests as req

resp = req.get("https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt")
text = resp.text

# Conditions
while True:
    check_input = str(input("What do you want to search? "))
    if check_input == "":  # if no value is entered for the string
        continue
    if check_input in text:  # string in present in the text file
        print("Matched")
        break
    else:  # string is absent in the text file
        print("No such string found, try again")
        continue
```

**Output**

```
What do you want to search? something
No such string found, try again
What do you want to search? SPACE
Matched
```